# Starting a process for all users as root (case of jupyter notebook server)

Tags: debian, users, python3, jupyter

This might be a peculiar case where we need to start the `jupyter notebook` for all system users on a common machine. All users have their own conda envs (installed in their home) which has same name `base`. However, for simplicity, we would like to start jupyter notebook after restart using a script for all users.

**Present case, works for 2-3 users.**

Ask user to execute from their bash session

```
tmux 
conda activate base
jupyter notebook --ip a.b.c.d -- port pqrs
```

followed by `Ctrl+b`, `d` to close the tmux session.

---

**New case (larger number of users)**

Script run by `root` which starts the jupyter server for each user on a specific port.

For this we have prepared a bash script which starts the notebook on an empty port for the current user.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"

conda activate base

current_env=$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
echo -e "\t ----------\n\t Current conda environment : " $current_env

################################################
#  get an empty port number between a range

used=$(ss -tulpn | grep -e9{700..800} | awk '{print $5}' | grep -o -E '[^:]+$' | xargs)

#echo -e "\t\t Currently used ports : $used"

# function to generate random number within a range
rnd() {
  out=$(shuf -i 9700-9800 -n 1)
  echo $out
}

val=$(rnd)

# this loop breaks when val is not found in string
while  grep -q "$val" <<<"$string"; do
   #echo "port being used"
   val=$(rnd)
done

#echo "$val"
port=$val

################################################

jupyter notebook --ip a.b.c.d  --port "$port" # start on specific port

################################################
status=$(ss -tulpn  | grep "jupyter" | grep "$port")
echo -e "\t\t $status \n\n"
```

Permission : users can read files from other user. Execution not allowed (even for root) in other users home.

**Question :** how to automate this as a root user so that all servers (for users) are started upon system restart.

- One way might be use `nohup` with the command instead of using `tmux`, and iterate over all users in a loop. Any ideas.

Not using other approach like `jupyterhub` since it requires Ubuntu and configuring PAM authentication is non-trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: I used JupyterHub in a container and simply mounted the passwd and shadow files inside.

Comment: @muru  : Could you give more details about how to do this with `jupyterhub`.